# Haskell,I need to create something like ATM function, stored multiple list in .txt file and retrieve the record

Tags: haskell-platform, haskell

Im new in haskell, i need some help with this program.
First, i store three accounts into a input.txt, so inside the file will got something like these ["1","steven","4000","12345"]["2","Marcus","5000","123456"]["3","Ivan","7000","12345"]There got 3 variables inside the account which are ID,name,balance and password. what i want to do is:

1. When the user type the password, the program will compare the password in the list with the password that user type and finally show the particular record
2. When the user want to transfer the money to another user. first insert the ID, second type the amount of money and finally the first account will reduce the money and the second account will increase the money.
3. The problem i face is how can i read a single account in order to compare, withdraw and transfer. Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks

```
import System.IO  

i :: IO()
i = do
    putStrLn "your ID : " 
    id<-getLine
    putStrLn "your name : "
    name<-getLine
    putStrLn "balance : "
    bal<- getLine
    putStrLn "password : "
    pass<- getLine
    let store2 =  [id]++[name]++[bal]++[pass]
    appendFile "input.txt" (show store2)

huhu ::IO()
huhu = do
    putStrLn "ID : "
    id<-getLine
    putStrLn "Password : "
    pass<-getLine
    rec <- readFile "input.txt"
    if ("pass" == rec) then
        do
        putStrLn "show information"
    else
        do 
        putStrLn "Wrong password"
```

Comment: Step 1 is ditch the file access and writing to output and implement a solution that takes a list of lists of strings like the example you gave, some input data like name and password and returns either the String representing the record or an error message String. Final step is to write main. Don't write main until the end. Don't write any IO until the end. Test each function as you write it using ghci.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should dive straight into properly structured data.
First, define some data types to help you solve the problem.

```
type ID = Int
data Account = Account {idno::ID, 
                        name :: String, 
                        balance :: Int, 
                        password :: String} deriving (Read,Show)
```

You might choose different types if you like.
This lets you define functions like

```
sameID :: ID -> Account -> Bool
sameID anID account = idno account == anID
```

Notice how the data label `idno` is also a handy function `Account -> ID`. We should use some sample data for testing:

```
sampleData = [Account 385634 "Fred" 234 "Iluvw1lm4",
              Account 405382 "Barney" (-23) "pebbles",
              Account 453464 "Wilma" 1432 "c4r3fu1n355 br33d5 pr0sp3r:ty"]
```

We can use this to test functions (and deduce that Barney has no clue whatsoever about password security or financial management).

Now you need to decide whether to use `Data.Map` to store your accounts using their IDs, or a list. Lists are easier to read from a file, but Maps are easier to do finding. So either do:

```
type Accounts = [Account]
```

Or use maps:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map  -- Put this at the top of the file if so.
type Accounts = Map.Map ID Account
```

Either way you'll need

```
findUserByID :: Accounts -> ID -> Maybe Account
findUserByID = undefined    -- you can work this out
```

If you're using a Map, you need to find it. Either browse the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map-Strict.html) - a good plan in any case, or use [the hoogle search engine](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to find it. If you're not sure, you can hoogle for `Map ID Account -> Maybe Account` and whilst it will warn you it doesn't know about ID or Account, the function you need is there! You'd be better off searching for `Map id account -> Maybe account` so it knows it can use a general function.

If you're using lists, you'll need to `filter` the list with a function that gives you true when the ID matches and false otherwise: `sameID` will help.

You'll also need

```
updateByID :: ID -> Account -> Accounts -> Accounts
updateByID anId newaccount = undefined   -- you can work this out too
```

but far more useful will be

```
updateUsingID :: Account -> Accounts -> Accounts
updateUsingID acc = updateByID (idno acc) acc
```

If you're using Maps, that will be easy, but if you're using lists, you'll need to to `map` a function like

```
onlyChange :: Account -> (Account -> Account)
onlyChange newacc acc | idno acc == idno newacc = newacc
                      | otherwise = acc
```

You can define

```
showAccount :: Account -> String
showAccount acc = undefined -- use the functions, eg  name acc ++ ....
                            -- or just use show
```

and functions like

```
changePassword :: String -> Account -> Account
changePassword newpwd acc = acc {password = newpwd}
```

Using the idea in `changePassword` and the function `balance`, you should be able to write

```
changeBalance :: (Int -> Int) -> Account -> Account
changeBalance = undefined   -- you try
```

Then you can write

```
pay :: Int -> Account -> Account -> (Account,Account)
pay amount fromAcc toAcc = undefined
```

hint: use `changeBalance (+ amount)` and `changeBalance (subtract amount)`.

Finally you'll need

```
updateTwoUsingID :: (Account,Account) -> Accounts -> Accounts
updateTwoUsingID (new1,new2) = updateUsingID new1 . updateUsingID new2
```

I couldn't resist telling you that one because it's a lovely example of function composition.

If you're finding it hard to use the `Maybe Account` stuff, ignore it until the end, just like we're ignoring file IO till the end. Functions like `fmap` and `>>=` are handy when working with `Maybe`. Look them up, or ditch the Maybe altogether for now and use hard `error`s. (Eg `!` in Map gives errors instead of Nothing.) Maybe is better than runtime errors, but maybe you'll get away with errors for now.

There's some gluing together to do, then some file input/output to do. For the file input/output, it would be simplest to use `read` and `show` on your `Accounts`.

You don't have to do it this way - this is just one approach. (Well, two, if you count list vs map as two approaches.) Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the effort!At least i know something now! Thanks again!

Comment: when i add "import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map" on the top of the file, it show the error "ERROR file:.\testing.txt - Can't find imported module "Data.Map.Strict""

Comment: @user1767145 sorry - remove the `.Strict` and it'll be OK.

Comment: i found this function, how can i open the input.txt file to operate this function? "findKey :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v  
findKey key = foldr (\(k,v) acc -> if key == k then Just v else acc) Nothing"

Comment: Good find - you can use lists but keep the functionality of Map with that one, but remember not to do file input till the end - use the sampleData instead for testing.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, all the problem boils down to your 3rd question. What you are looking for is a data structure allowing you to *map* user names to user accounts. I suggest looking at the [`Data.Map`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map.html) container type and see how you can use it.